# Working with filtered std::ranges when the filter is expensive?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

I've noticed that, e.g., `std::ranges::to<std::vector>(vals | std::views::filter(expensive));` evaluates `expensive` twice: Once when `std::vector`'s constructor computes `std::distance(beg, end)` to figure out the allocation it needs, and then again when it actually constructs the items. Is there a good way around this?

The best I can think of are:

1. Is there a way to make `vals | std::views::filter(expensive)` present as a `std::ranges::input_range` so `std::ranges::to` falls back to repeated insertions?
2. I could always do `std::ranges::copy(vals | std::views::filter(expensive), std::back_inserter(result));` either with or without reserving in `result`.
3. Something else?

In general, if I'm producing a view-range that I know to be expensive to filter, I could see good reason to have a `std::views::expensive_filter(f)` that acts like `std::views::filter` but makes a `std::ranges::input_range`.

Comment: Option two seems to be the most suitable choice.

Comment: But are we guaranteed that `cooy` wouldn’t try to do some optimization shenanigans? It seems like the only robust solution is 1…

Comment: Perhaps. For the first option, I think you can try to convert the original range into *coroutine*, that is, `co_yield` one element at a time.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6GY81sqzq).

Comment: @康桓瑋 that is beautifully concise and yet totally overkill. I kind of love it :-D